# Cached Controller Method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I'm trying to make some changes to the show method in my events controller and noticed the changes making zero difference. I commented out the @event = Event.find_by_slug(params[:slug]) line and the show view still works and does not produce an error! I even deleted the entire show method and it still works. I thought for a moment I was working on a copy of the app, but it's definitely the correct one.

I've never had this problem before, but did recently upgrade my Rails version from 3.2.0 to 3.2.13. Wondering if there's a caching setting somewhere that's causing this. Has anyone experienced similar or got any pointers on where to look for a caching config setting perhaps?

EDIT - Code added

```
  def show
   @event = Event.find_by_slug(params[:slug])
   @meta_title = "#{@event.headline} at #{@event.venue.name}, #{@event.venue.town} - #{@event.event_date.to_date.to_formatted_s(:my_format)}"
   @meta_description = "#{@event.info.to_s.truncate(380, :separator => " ")}"
   @facebook_image = "#{@event.event_image.url(:large)}"
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @event }
    end
  end
```

The view is quite large, but I would call fields using something like this:

```
<h2><%= @event.headline %> TEST</h2>
```

'TEST' is something I just added to see if that would be rendered and it is, so i'm definitely editing the correct version of the app.

EDIT - New development in finding this bug

After extensive searches for dupe actions etc I gradually started trying to manually find the cause. First by scaffolding a new model and seeing if the same behaviour occurred and it didn't. Then looking at what was different, top to bottom in my event controller I started to comment out lines/actions and then test behaviour. Anyway, commenting out `load_and_authorize_resource` which I am using to call the CanCan gem and it's ability model the caused my app to behave as it should do, obviously now without my role based code.

Can anyone think why CanCan could be causing this?

Comment: this really sounds like you're working on a wrong copy of the document or possibly the wrong controller, or maybe have some weird duplicate actions in your controller.or maybe looking at a remote copy of the app instead of looking at the localhost one.. you wouldn't be the first one to do such a mistake..

Comment: I'm definitely in the right version of the app, if I amend the show view with some static text it's visible on refresh. I did think about duped actions but have searched and reviewed all instances of Event.find and can't see any that could be doing it. It's going to be shockingly simple when I find it, I just know it!

Comment: can you show your controller, action and the view?

Comment: How are you starting up the app? Have you modified any application settings?

Comment: @Zippie - i'll add code above in a sec

Comment: @DaveNewton with the standard rails s command. I've not modified any settings but as I say, I did recently upgrade my Rails version.

Comment: can you restart your server and try again?

Comment: I've tried that and even restarted my Mac

Comment: do you have some before filter that would fetch the `@event`?

Comment: Not that I can find, but I think it's something like that causing it. If I strip my view back to just `@event.headline` and then change `@event` to `@event_show` in both the view and controller, they are then working together as they should. I suppose I could fix by doing that across the show view, but I want to get to the bottom of this problem incase it's going to happen elsewhere.

Comment: maybe you have some sort of `caches_action` set?

Comment: It looks that there are lots of possibilities. Perhaps try to force refresh browser (shift+cmd+r), do `Rails.cache.clear` or delete `app/tmp` folder. Also, the routes for that particular resource might be custom.

Comment: Still not got to the bottom of this one. I've tried all suggestions and nothing is working. Scaffolded a new model to see if issue occurred on that and it doesn't so it's definitely leaning towards there being some kind of duplication somewhere, though i've done extensive app and system searches that don't show any duplication anywhere. At a bit of a loss on this one.

Comment: New bug finding development added to main question....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CanCan have both `load_resource`, `authorize_resource` and `load_and_authorize_resource`. They all do what they say, so in your example will `load_resource` set the `@event` instance variable `@event = Event.find(params[:id])`. `authorize_resource` will just call `authorize! @event` before each action. `load_and_authorize_resource` will fist load the resource and then authorize as before.

Here is another example from the [CanCan documentation on github](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan):

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def show
    # @article is already loaded and authorized
  end
end
```

Comment: Holy crap! That seems to be it! What a wild goose chase that was. Not sure I understand the purpose of `load_and_authorize_resource' but changing to just `authorize_resource' seems to have fixed it. Thank you so much.

Comment: The reason behind `load_and_authorize_resource` is to authorize against the resource record (like `@event`). If you just user `authorize_resource` will you authorize against the class instead (like `Event`). You can however create your own before filter to load the resource in any way you want, just it's loaded before the `authorize_resource` before filter is runned. You can read more here: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/authorizing-controller-actions#authorize_resource