# Identifying source of instance variable using Rails debugger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, instance-variables

This question is related to the unsolved issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749073/cached-controller-method).

Is it possible using Rails debugger or something similar to identify and trace the source of an instance variable (or other variable)?

I have `@venue` being passed to my `Venue` `show`view from my `Venue` `show` action, but I seem to have a rogue or duplicate version of `@venue` somewhere else in my app. When I comment out `@venue = Venue.find(params[:id])` in my `Venue` controller `show` action, the `show` view still works, while it should throw an error. I need to trace this duplicate.

Comment: I don't think so. Have you considered using grep? You sure you don't accidentally reassign it in the view, partial, or helper? Do you have any filters?

Comment: No, how could I go about that?

Comment: ... Grep for "@venue" in all your `.rb` files. And probably view files. Consider using `ack` instead, too.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at `Better Errors`. There is a [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/402-better-errors-railspanel?view=asciicast) with all the details. Just install

```
group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
end
```

You need the `binding_of_caller` gem for the extra functionality

For any line of the stack trace you can view the local and instance variables at any point in the stack. It also has an interactive prompt that you can use at any point in the stack trace. I've been using it for a few months and It has really helped me out.

You will easily be able to trace what is going on with `@venue` and its duplicates.